# Installing latest version of GitKraken 6.5.0 on Kubuntu 19.10 via snap show wrong version

Tags: kubuntu, snap, 19.10

I am using GitKraken on Kubuntu 19.10 and installed via snap.

My GitKraken app about info shows using version 6.4.1 as seen at below screenshot:

[image: GitKraken version v.6.4.1]

When I check via command line and Snap Store (https://snapcraft.io/gitkraken), it shows the latest version is 6.5.0.

```
da@ffof:~$ snap list gitkraken 
Name       Version  Rev  Tracking  Publisher   Notes
gitkraken  6.5.0    150  stable    gitkraken✓  -
da@ffof:~$ sudo snap refresh gitkraken 
snap "gitkraken" has no updates available
```

[image: https://snapcraft.io/gitkraken]

Here is `sudo find / -iname gitkraken` output:

```
/tmp/snap.gitkraken/tmp/.snap/snap/gitkraken
/home/da/snap/gitkraken
/home/da/snap/gitkraken/151/.config/GitKraken
/home/da/snap/gitkraken/150/.config/GitKraken
/var/snap/gitkraken
/snap/bin/gitkraken
/snap/gitkraken
/snap/gitkraken/151/usr/share/gitkraken
/snap/gitkraken/151/usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken
/snap/gitkraken/150/usr/share/gitkraken
/snap/gitkraken/150/usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken
```

Comment: I have just installed gitkraken via snap on 19.10 and have only 6.5.0 on my system. My suspicion is that you have 2 copies installed on your system. Can you give the results of: `sudo find / -iname gitkraken` please? The snap version lives in `/snap/bin/gitkraken` which is at the lowest priority in the `$PATH` statement...